# Conversion of a verb into adjective

Tags: usage

How are verbs converted into adjectives

In the following sentence can I use both **craved for** and **sought after**

> Power got with money is the most **craved for/sought after** today

My book says in the above sentence **craved for** is correct, but I don't understand why **sought after** is not correct

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You've given 2 examples of phrasal/compound adjectives - see https://grammarist.com/grammar/phrasal-adjectives/. Did you mean you wanted the verbs? 

Accordingly, I believe that it should be "craved-for" and "sought-after" (hyphenated) but those are just the rules - I understood it well enough :)

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 1):

English allows words to morph back and forth between nouns, verbs, and adjectives. We call something a 'home', for example. But a dog can 'home', and we have 'home-fries'. These words are all related, obviously. The noun 'home' is 'the place I go at night, the place I live'. The dog who 'homes' is seeking a given destination (in this case a thing) just like the man who is eager to get home. And 'home-fries' would be claiming to be 'fries like your mother made at home."

So in this case we have the verb 'crave'; meaning 'to strongly desire'. I crave home-fries. My desire itself is called a 'craving'; the same root plus a suffix which turns the verb into a noun.

The adjective, as you point out, is a little harder than with 'home fries' or 'train track'. We don't speak of craved-fries. Instead we use, as you point out, the expression 'craved-for'. Thus we have the 'craved-for home-fries'.

So, verb, "to crave"; noun, "craving", adjective, "craved-for". For many words we also allow an adverb, but I can't think of one for 'crave' ('cravenly' is NOT right, I looked it up. It comes via a different route.) But we do have 'homely', so there's that :)

Note: sometimes the word gets buried in another word. Thus 'homesick' has the word 'home' acting as an adjective in the front of the word. It ends up meaning 'feeling sick because I'm not at home'.